# Creating an empty file inside a folder

Tags: files, home, touch

Does anyone know how to enter a Linux command to create an empty file called `test1` in the directory `systems` while you are still in your home directory using the touch command?

Comment: Yes what have you tried?

Comment: @Ned64 why did you delete your correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
touch /path_to_the_systems_directory/test1
```

This should work given you have the necessary privileges to write on the directory